# Will putting a sleep on a thread clog up OS's thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some CPU performance issues on my C++ program that uses 2 threads. On some occasions, I have an option to use my own check mechanism on a while loop or a sleep statement.

The question is:

Will the sleep statement clog up an OS's (in my case windows) thread or will the OS optimize it in such a way that the sleeping thread is freed and another process can use it until the sleep is over?

There is also the distinction between Windows.h Sleep and chrono sleep, currently I'm using Windows.h Sleep but I can opt in to use chrono sleep if adviced so.

Comment: FWIW [`std::chrono::sleep` is implemented using WIN32 sleep](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2261f7edb760eb3fe0726187c818b796dc7ea798/stl/src/cthread.cpp#L75), If you're having performance issues we'll need to see the code in question or more specifically a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Sleep on the mainthread is a bad idee, it will totally halt any thread. So never use it on the mainthread, on background threads it can kind of be used (for small durations). For longer durations you need to be able to have an interruptible sleep (to react quickly to shutdown/cancel/abort situations). In this case use condition_variable with wait timeout. Anyway I always try to make designs in which sleeps are NOT necessary and some kind of (interthread) signalling is used.

Comment: In a GUI application where the UI is in one thread sleeping on that main thread is not good for user experience since that usually means the UI becomes unresponsive. In windows if the UI is unresponsive for a long time it may complain and ask the user if they want to kill the the process.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which "sleep" function you are asking about, but [`std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) does *nothing.* It does nothing for the specified `duration` of time, and then it returns.

Because it does nothing, in any reasonable implementation of `sleep_for` on a multi-processing operating system, the OS will swap the thread out for the `duration`, so that other threads may use the CPU.

Most "sleep" functions in most programming languages, including [`std::this_thread::sleep_until(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) work the same way.

> Will the sleep statement clog up...?

Since other threads are allowed to use the CPU for the duration of any sleep-like call, you normally don't have to worry about the sleep call "clogging up" anything. But, there's a couple of mistakes that newbies sometimes make with `sleep`-like functions. Using sleep incorrectly *can* clog things up in these specific situations:

**Sleeping while holding a mutex locked**

We lock a mutex when we want one thread to have exclusive use of some resource. But, if the thread that locked the mutex is sleeping, then it's *not* using the shared resource. It's doing *nothing* with the resource (`sleep` does nothing) and it's not letting any other thread use the resource either.

Keeping a mutex locked while sleeping (or, while waiting for *anything,* really) is practically always a mistake.

**Sleeping in a GUI event handler**

Most GUI frameworks have a thread that loops forever, waiting for events, and calling *event handlers* that were registered by the program. For example, if you want your program to react to some button press, you probably register some "onClick(...)" or "onButtonPress(...)" handler function that will be called whenever the user clicks your button.

If one of your handlers sleeps when it is called by the event loop, then the event loop thread will do *nothing* for the duration ("sleep" does nothing.) In particular, the thread is not awaiting or reacting to events while it's in your handler function. In most GUI frameworks, the whole UI will appear to "freeze" for the duration if any event handler sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

A sleep is intended to do what is says. I.e., it will pause the thread and leave the CPUs to other threads/processes.
In other words, a sleep won't clog up the OS.

Answer (score 1):

A `Sleep` call tells the OS that it can reassign the CPU core to other threads, potentially in other processes. But the OS can always do this anyway. `Sleep` *also* tells the OS that the thread should not get any CPU core back in the mean time.

`std::chrono` is the C++ standard way, and will also work on Linux and MacOSX.